# Usage of neither/nor vs none

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, sentence-patterns

Which is the correct option between these two lines?
1) *But none of your obnoxiousness or charm*

2) *But neither of your obnoxiousness nor charm*

I'm writing a poem for somebody and am currently confused between the two choices. English is obviously not my native language so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Both are grammatical and mean the same thing, but only if you eliminate "of" in the second.  I started to add this answer, but someone else (i.e., @Hugh) got it in before me, so I never actually posted it but just gave his answer an up-vote.

Answer (score 1):

The first suggestion is fine:

> 1) But none of your obnoxiousness or charm

The second example needs a bit of unpicking:

> 2) But neither **of** your...

excludes two similar features/ objects/ people. "Neither of your shoes is a good fit;" "Neither of your brothers are as clever as you."
It is better to leave out the **'or.'**

> 2) But neither your obnoxiousness nor charm...

Have a look at the answer [here](https:///english.stackexchange.com/questions/146576/)